# How to show the old contents after clearing the search

Tags: reactjs, redux

After showing the content for searched item, while removing the letters from search bar not showing the contents correctly. How to show the contents based on the word which is there in search bar. I have started to learn redux. So need some suggestions

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [searchTerm, setSearchterm] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.add);
  console.log(data, "dfata");
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };
  console.log(name);
  if (data.length == 0) {
    return <p>No data</p>;
  }

  const Submithandler = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_ITEM", name });
    setName("");
  };
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearchterm(e.target.value);
  };
  const submitSerach = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "SEARCH_ITEM", searchTerm });
  };
  const reset = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "RESET", searchTerm });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.loading && <p>loading</p>}
      <input value={searchTerm} onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)} />
      <button onClick={() => submitSerach()}>search</button>
      <button onClick={() => reset()}>reset</button>
      <input value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={Submithandler}>Add</button>

      {data.item.length === 0 && <p>no item</p>}
      {data.item.map((dta, i) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {dta}
            <button
              onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_ITEM", name: dta })}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  item: [],
  loading: false,
};

function addReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_ITEM":
      console.log(action, "ahghsgda");
      return { item: [...state.item, action.name] };
    case "REMOVE_ITEM":
      console.log(action, "REMOPVE");
      return {
        item: state.item.filter((inditem) => inditem !== action.name),
      };
    case "SEARCH_ITEM":
      console.log(action, "ahghsgda");
      const data = [...state.item];
      return {
        loading: true,
        item: [data.filter((product) => product.includes(action.searchTerm))],
      };
    case "RESET":
      return {
        item: [...state.item],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default addReducer;
```

After showing the content for searched item, while removing the letters from search bar not showing the contents correctly

Comment: I think you shouldn't change the items array by searching. Or even better you shouldn't handle search logic using redux and should handle it locally in the component.

Comment: Before diving straight into your issue, I'd recommend to explain your app first. I can sort of derive from reading the code what is happening there, but you're not giving us a lot of context. Who is searching for what and how exactly?

Comment: I'm adding the list of contents in 'add_item" case and searching for the added list items in search box